# Simple SQL query won't work when using an in clause

Tags: sql-server

`Field1` has value 183872 in it but the following query doesn't return anything

```
select * 
from table1 
where field1 in ('Abbott,Christina D - 183872')
```

Comment: What is the value of `field1`? exactly `183872`? Or it just contains that as a substring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't what `in` is for.  You need to use `like`.  Also, is field1 a numeric field? If so, you should need to cast/convert to string:

```
select * 
from table1 
where 'Abbott,Christina D - 183872' like '%' + cast(field1 as varchar(10)) + '%'
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because `in` doesn't mean "value is contained within the following string", but instead means "value is contained within the following set of values".

SQLServer is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For the query to work correctly it would have to be something like

```
select * 
from table1 
where field1 in ('183872','22244','2224455')
```

You could do something like the following

```
select * 
from table1 
where field1 like '%183872%'
```

That would bring back all records with 183872 in it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer IN is used to test against a set of values.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE COUNTRY IN ('USA','CANADA','MEXICO');
```

You can use CHARINDEX() to find the position of a string within another string.

```
select * from table1 
where CHARINDEX(field1,'Abbott,Christina D - 183872') > 0
```